# Do not load registry changes with IE instances opened from VBS

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, registry

If i open manually some IE, and then make a registry change, when i open a new instance it will show the change (per example the useragent)

If i do this in VBS:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.navigate "www.download.com"
ie.Visible = True
```

It will open a new instance of IE but it will NOT show the changes i made before in the registry, why?

What i am looking is to change the proxy and/or the useragent.
It works fine when i manually open the IE after making changes in the registry, but does not work in if create the new IE instance using VBS.

Any help are welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

You code doesn't create a new instance of IE. Remember IE is one IE to control other IEs.

See how child process have the PID of parent in command line. See the embedding switch (means started by COM).

```
CommandLine                                                                   Name          ProcessId  

"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" -Embedding                 iexplore.exe  3260       

"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" SCODEF:3260 CREDAT:145409  iexplore.exe  2080       

"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" SCODEF:3260 CREDAT:145411  iexplore.exe  864
```

Now I open another IE from start menu.

```
CommandLine                                                                  Name          ProcessId  

"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" -Embedding                 iexplore.exe  3260       

"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" SCODEF:3260 CREDAT:145409  iexplore.exe  2080       

"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" SCODEF:3260 CREDAT:145411  iexplore.exe  864        

"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"                            iexplore.exe  2800       

"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" SCODEF:2800 CREDAT:79873   iexplore.exe  2568
```

See we now have two host IE, one with the new one and one with the old one.

Comment: Thnaks for your answer. But im running this code from my desktop in a vbs file. And it does not show the registry changes. Im not running this code from inside some IE. So i understand what you mean, but does not see how to avoid it. How can i open another instance from vbs.

Comment: I want to open some IE from a vbs code, and i want that IE to show registry changes, just as if i open a new instance. It is possible? Thanks for the time to repoly my answer :)

Comment: Open a new instance and use this to get a reference `Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application"):Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows:For Each window in AllWindows:msgbox window.locationname:Next`

Comment: Thanks, but how to create a new instance using vbs? If i run a vbs from outside any IE and all IE are closed (need to be closed even if we run the vbs from outside the IE?). Does it open a new instance? Last question: how did you see the parent that you showed me? Thanks again and esxcuse me for asking too much.

Comment: Just execute a new instance of IE, `wshshell.run "iexplore www.site.com"`, (I gave the IE way above - this if office type way but may work for IE but not sure as IE doesn't list itself in the Running Object Table) then use `Set x = GetObject(,"www.site.com")`. Task info can be got from `tasklist /v` and `wmic process get /format:list`.